# Check the availability of devices on the network

Tags: python, c#, powershell

What is the best way to create software client (service) that installs and then runs in the background. When you turn on the device (where the service is installed), this service will automatically send network availability information of device to web server. On web server will be only state of devices on network. (on/off)

So what is the optimal solution for create software client? Using powershell, python or other?
Do you have anyone experience with similar problem?

Comment: What OS do you need to support?

Comment: I need to support only windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to support Windows, you can write Windows Service (using C#). It starts automatically (you don't even need to login into windows), on start of the service you can send "I'm on" message, and on stop "I'm off" one. Also this service can respond on "Are you on" requests from the server.

Here is a tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Sending messages are pretty straight forward (just use `HttpClient`), receiving them is a bit more complicated.

You need to create a listener:

```cs
var listener = new HttpListener
{
    AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
    Prefixes =
    {
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"]
    }
};
```

Then you need to listen for messages:

```cs
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    if (ValidateCredentials(context))
    {
        continue;
    }

    string body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd().ToLower();
    ProcessAction(body);
}
```

Also you can validate credentials, if you want:

```cs
bool ValidateCredentials(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    var identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
    Debug.WriteLine($"-u {identity.Name} -p {identity.Password}");

    string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"];
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
    if (identity.Name != user || identity.Password != password)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look at tools like Zabbix. With that tool you can monitor network resources in different ways. I use it to monitor the enterprise network and important devices, you can even create a visual map showing the state of each device.

What you are intending to do is covered by SNMP (simple network management protocol).
If you can tell me more details on what you expect to do may be I can give you more advice...

Comment: Thank you for the monitoring software but i want to create a software client. After turning on the device where the software is installed, it sends the status of the device to the web application. The web application will display the devices (on which the software is installed) as well as their status.
I think it would be appropriate to use the arp protocol in the service.